# Where is Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy's sendTo?

Tags: string, networking, haskell, bytestring

Both `Network.Socket.ByteString` and `Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy` have a `send` function.

`Network.Socket.ByteString` has a `sendTo` function, but `Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy` doesn't.

How can I use `Network.Socket.ByteString`'s sendTo with a Lazy.ByteString *or* `Network.Socket.ByteString.Lazy`'s `send` function.  (i.e. how do I tell it where to send the packet.)

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial on Haskell's Strings, BytesStrings. Lazy.ByteStrings, etc. as I find them very confusing (coming from a Java/Python background).

Comment: Note that `sendTo` is strict in the data sent, and so there's no real logic to passing it a lazy bytestring. That's why the function only exists on strict bytestrings.

Comment: @sclv - yours is the correct answer (mine is a solution).  Could you post your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that sendTo is strict in the data sent, and so there's no real logic to passing it a lazy bytestring. That's why the function only exists on strict bytestrings.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to make a new function:

```
import Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

lazyToStrictBS :: LBS.ByteString -> BS.ByteString
lazyToStrictBS x = BS.concat $ LBS.toChunks x
```

and use it to convert the `Lazy.ByteString` into a normal `ByteString`.

Here's the converse, so that I find it when I google this problem again in future.

```
import Data.ByteString as BS
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS

strictToLazyBS :: BS.ByteString -> LBS.ByteString
strictToLazyBS x = LBS.fromChunks [x]
```

Comment: It is very uncommon to interact with sockets directly in most modern programs﹘which is why most applications that I know of use some form of abstraction (Like [`pipes-network`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-network)) for lazy byte strings. Also, +1 for "so that I find it when I google this problem again in future" :)